# X keeps restarting without getting to login screen

Tags: gnome, xorg, gdm, gnome-session

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 in my PC. Two days ago, oneconf crashed while I was working and I had to restart the computer. Since then, I haven't been able to go past the black screen to the login screen, after booting.

I used the CLI console tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) to check syslog, Xorg.0.log, dmesg, etc. I got the following message repeated over and over in syslog:

```
Apr  9 00:40:11 atul gnome-session[16679]: WARNING: IceLockAuthFile failed: Permission denied
Apr  9 00:40:11 atul gdm-simple-slave[16479]: GLib-GObject: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Apr  9 00:40:11 atul gdm-simple-slave[16479]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Apr  9 00:40:12 atul acpid: client 16484[0:0] has disconnected
Apr  9 00:40:12 atul acpid: client 16484[0:0] has disconnected
Apr  9 00:40:12 atul acpid: client connected from 16752[0:0]
Apr  9 00:40:12 atul acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Apr  9 00:40:12 atul acpid: client connected from 16752[0:0]
Apr  9 00:40:12 atul acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Apr  9 00:40:12 atul gdm-simple-slave[16747]: Failed to give slave programs access to the display. Trying to proceed.
```

Moreover, my (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>) session keeps getting interrupted by the main GUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>).  It looks like the X/gdm keeps restarting in an infinite loop.

I wasn't able to find any direct solution on the web. But I tried some solutions given for similar problems. I tried reconfiguring gdm, xserver-xorg. I tried reinstalling xserver-xorg, gdm, gnome-shell, gnome-session, etc. I tried removing ubuntu-gnome-desktop entirely and use unity instead. None of them worked. When I tried using lightdm instead of gdm, I got "System running in low graphics mode" error. When I tried recovery mode with failsafe GUI, my failsafeX did not start.

When I tried startx in my CUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>), I get a GUI at <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F78</kbd>. But I still get interrupted by (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>) when gdm restarts. When I stop gdm service, my applications start crashing in my GUI.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Does the Xorg.0.log have any errors before it restarts X?

Comment: I have the same issue with 15.04, I'm sure it's related to graphics card as NVidia logo pops up now and then. Today I actually run `do-release-upgrade -d` just to get rid of it and it seems to work. Not really a solution thought. In the past I used to manually reinstall the proprietary NVidia driver and it always helped, just lost my nerve this time.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me when I installed the samba package before I knew about:

`smbpasswd -a zero`

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>

Login.

Check it:

```
$ ls -la /home/zero
```

Change ownership back to the default scheme:

```
$ chown zero:zero .
$ chown zero:zero ..
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>

Login to xwindows.

If you read that, syslog says: WARNING: IceLockAuthFile failed: Permission denied. Now it should be able to create the file with the default scheme in place. lol